# Easy way to get a list of every item in a google drive folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Exactly as the title says, is there an easy way to get a list of every item in a google drive folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the google drive documentation the `files.list` method returns all the files that a user has. You can read more about authenticating users [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk).